# Unable to add SAML signing option of an Enterprise application in Azure AD through MS Graph API using Java SDK

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

List definitionList = new LinkedList<>();
definitionList.add(
"{ "TokenIssuancePolicy":{"TokenResponseSigningPolicy":"ResponseAndToken","SamlTokenVersion":"2.0","SigningAlgorithm":"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256","Version":1}}");

```
    TokenIssuancePolicy newPolicy = new TokenIssuancePolicy();
    newPolicy.definition = definitionList;
    newPolicy.displayName = "sample-app";
    newPolicy = serviceClient.policies().tokenIssuancePolicies().buildRequest().post(newPolicy);
    
    System.out.println("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenIssuancePolicies/"+newPolicy.id);

    TokenIssuancePolicyCollectionWithReferencesPage policyPage = serviceClient.servicePrincipals(principal.id).tokenIssuancePolicies().buildRequest().get();
    List<TokenIssuancePolicy> policyList = policyPage.getCurrentPage();

    System.out.println(policyPage.getCount());
    if (Objects.isNull(policyList) || policyList.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    }
    policyList.forEach(app1 -> System.out.println(app1.displayName + "         :  " + app1.id));
    
    TokenIssuancePolicy policy = new TokenIssuancePolicy();
    policy.additionalDataManager().put("@odata.id", new JsonPrimitivenew JsonPrimitive("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenIssuancePolicies/" + newPolicy.id));
    System.out.println(policy.additionalDataManager());
    serviceClient.servicePrincipals(principal.id).tokenIssuancePolicies().references().buildRequest().post(policy);
```

Above is the code which Iam trying to update the policy of an Enterprise application but ending up with an Invalid object identifier 'null'.
Could anyone help me on this.
Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c45SP.png)

Comment: Could you please tell me which line code you get error?

Comment: The error is at this line policy.additionalDataManager().put("@odata.id", new JsonPrimitive("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/tokenissuancepolicies/9e59ce9d-4b92-456c-a996-e09331ea3db2"+newPolicy.id));

Comment: @JimXu I have attached the screenshot of the error as well. Could you let me know if you have an idea of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, we cannot use the code `TokenIssuancePolicy policy = new TokenIssuancePolicy(); policy.additionalDataManager().put("@odata.id", new JsonPrimitivenew JsonPrimitive("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenIssuancePolicies/" + newPolicy.id));` to create a new policy. We need to update code as below
`TokenIssuancePolicy policy = new TokenIssuancePolicy(); policy.id=tokenIssuancePolicy.id;`

For example

```
 TokenIssuancePolicy tokenIssuancePolicy = new TokenIssuancePolicy();
        LinkedList<String> definitionList = new LinkedList<String>();
        definitionList.add("{\r\n  \"TokenIssuancePolicy\": {\r\n    \"Version\": 1,\r\n    \"SigningAlgorithm\": \"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256\",\r\n    \"TokenResponseSigningPolicy\": \"ResponseAndToken\",\r\n    \"SamlTokenVersion\": \"2.0\"\r\n  }\r\n}");
        tokenIssuancePolicy.definition = definitionList;
        tokenIssuancePolicy.displayName = "mytest";

        tokenIssuancePolicy= graphClient.policies().tokenIssuancePolicies()
            .buildRequest()
            .post(tokenIssuancePolicy);
        System.out.println("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenIssuancePolicies/"+tokenIssuancePolicy.id);

        TokenIssuancePolicy policy = new TokenIssuancePolicy();
        policy.id=tokenIssuancePolicy.id;

         policy =graphClient.servicePrincipals("00964c82-a7c2-4675-bbed-54bcf16328b3").tokenIssuancePolicies().references()
                .buildRequest()
                .post(policy);
        System.out.println("-----------"+policy.id);
```

[image]